# Change attribute inside order product row

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, orders, sku

I want to change the default SKU attribute (product number) inside the orderview, at the items block, to a custom attribute.

See:

[image]

Currently by default the SKU is displayed, I want to change this into the DPN (my custom created attribute).

The attribute code for this is: dpn.

How can I achieve that?

I edit the file:

/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Items/Column/Default.php

From default code:

```
public function getSku()
{
    /*if ($this->getItem()->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
        return $this->getItem()->getProductOptionByCode('simple_sku');
    }*/
    return $this->getItem()->getSku();
}
```

To:

```
public function getSku()
{
    /*if ($this->getItem()->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
        return $this->getItem()->getProductOptionByCode('simple_sku');
    }*/
    return $this->getItem()->getDpn();
}
```

But that does not work. When I change the value to `return $this->getItem()->getProductId();` Then I get the Product Id, so that does work.

How can I get the data from the attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The good solutions was:

```
public function getSku()
{
    /*if ($this->getItem()->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
        return $this->getItem()->getProductOptionByCode('simple_sku');
    }*/
    return Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($this->getItem()->getProductId(), 'dpn');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change 'name' column in Order View -> Items Ordered in Magento Admin:

1) Add layout update:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_items">
        <action method="addColumnRender">
            <column>name</column>
            <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</block>
            <template>neklo_custom/sales/items/column/name.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

2) Copy template from `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/items/column/name.phtml`

to `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/neklo_custom/sales/items/column/name.phtml`

3) Change template content output

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I do not want to change the name. I want to change the SKU attribute inside an order. How can I change the displayed attribute?

Comment: Change output inside the 'Items Ordered' block on 'Order View' page in backend?
E.g. `Gym Bag
SKU: free-gym-bag, Size: One
Color: Black` change to `Gym Bag
MPN: mpn_example, Size: One
Color: Black` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is exactly what I mean. How can I achieve that?

Comment: See my edit, will that be a good solution?